# Knockout and punches plugin not rendering undefined observables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js, data-binding

I wrote the following code to populate a menu item:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Wallets <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        {{#if: !wallets}}
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Loading...</a></li>
        {{/if}}
        {{#foreach: wallets}}
        <li>
            <a href="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/Wallets/")){{id}}">{{linkText}}</a>
        </li>
        {{/foreach}}
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Add", "Wallets")"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Add new</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I'm using knockout.punches as I'm more into curly braces than data-binding every element. wallets is an observable array loaded and kept up-to-date by SignalR.

Ok so far, but this is the way the code is rendered before the wallets observable is defined:

[image: code snippet preview]

I'm new to knockout so maybe there's some clue I don't know about, but in general I've found little information on punches extension. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Do other "curly-punches" work as expected? Anyway consider to create minimal fiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Instead of `{{#if: !wallets}}`, you should use `{{#ifnot: wallets}}`. Also are you calling `ko.applyBindings`? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: I already tried #ifnot without success. I decided to switch to vue.js, way more active project than knockout.js nowadays, and everything is working as expected. Thank you anyway.